# Pouchdb changes to remote Couchdb fails with ETIMEDOUT (proxy in the middle)

Tags: javascript, express, proxy, couchdb, pouchdb

I have an angularjs web app that communicate with a remote CouchDB using PouchDB API, and in the middle there is a Node.js proxy (express-http-proxy) that intermediate between them.

When I try to get changes of a document through the homonym method, the request fails after some time (about 30 seconds) with ETIMEDOUT error, as in the following case:

```
USER INFO error: Error: ETIMEDOUT  user.service.js:190
 at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (pouchdb.js:11051)
 at timeoutReq (pouchdb.js:10995)
```

[image: Error message image]

In my code I call the .changes() method with the following parameters:

```
db.changes({
    since: 'now',
    live: true,
    include_docs: true,
    doc_ids: [userDocId],
    heartbeat: 1000
  }).on('change', function(change) {
    console.log("USER INFO change:",change);
  }).on('complete', function(info) {
    console.warn("USER INFO complete:",info);
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    console.error("USER INFO error:",err);
  });
```

If I also set the timeout parameter, the method fails after the number of  milliseconds that I set.

If a change arrives within the time the timeout error is postponed for another ~30 seconds. After the timeout error the other changes do not arrive anymore.

I use `.changes()` also for another request but for previous changes and all goes fine because it isn't live.

I would like it to remain active indefinitely but it seems that the heartbeat does not work as it should; is there any configuration or parameter missing that I should set?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In future questions, pls paste the error text from your console, so others can search it.

Comment: have you fixed this problem already? I am having the same problem right now